# What is the term used to describe when two items (maybe numbers) have been mixed up?

Tags: vocabulary

What is the term used to describe when two items have been mixed up (i.e.the month and day of a date of birth)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *mixed up*? Saying *Tuesday* instead of *Wednesday*? Saying *February, Tuesday 2, 2014*?

Answer (score 4):

*Transposed,* meaning when two or more things exchange places, as in "The month and the day were accidentally *transposed* when you filled out this form."

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is  to say that the items were **interchanged**.

From Collins dictionary:

> [interchange:](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/interchange) to change places or cause to change places; alternate; exchange; switch

Answer (score -2):

I would say "inverted".

Example:  Sorry, I **inverted** the month and day.  I meant February 10th, not October 2nd.

Here is the Merriam-Webster definition:  to change the position, order, or relationship of things so that they are the opposite of what they had been